# Is it possible to trigger a Broadacst receiver if Internet is already on?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I just want to know whether I a can trigger a Broadcast receiver when the net is already on? That is if i install the app when the internet is already on then will the broadacst receiver be triggered?

Comment: `BroadcastReceiver` for what? But the answer is most likely yes

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the broadcast receiver for network attach/detatch events?  Nope, it only fires when the state changes-  if an app wasn't installed when it was last fired, it won't get a special call for being newly installed.  It would, however, get it the next time the state changes.

Answer (score 0):

On later versions of Android, some (all?) broadcasts aren't sent to an app until it has been manually opened at least once.